# The difference between get and receive

Tags: word-usage, verbs, meaning-in-context, differences

> Yesterday, I *got* an email from Yahoo notifying me that the glitch had been fixed.
>
> Yesterday, I *received* an email from Yahoo notifying me that the glitch had been fixed.

They all mean that I have got an email from Yahoo yesterday, is there any subtle difference between them?

Comment: In this context, no difference in meaning, slight difference in register.

Comment: @Jim what does it mean 'in register'?

Comment: Google says, “a variety of a language or a level of usage, as determined by degree of formality and choice of vocabulary, pronunciation, and syntax, according to the communicative purpose, social context, and social status of the user.”

Comment: @Jim i see, but i still don't know the specific and subtle difference between them.

Comment: Basically one's more formal than the other.

Comment: Receive is considered more formal, because it is a loanword, while get is considered more informal. But you can write "get" in a formal English exam paper with no risk of receiving a penalty :)

Comment: @marcellothearcane  it makes sense. i have updated my question.

Comment: -1 Please include your research in your question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I know what you mean but calling *receive* a loanword sure does seem funny now almost a thousand years later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Received" has a more formal tone than "got", but also, in this instance "received" might carry a hint of movement in [willingly] "taking into one's possession" ... a sort of coming into one's possession with one's acquiescence.  That hint is completely missing with "got".  This aspect becomes rather clearer if you were to consider changing the item being conveyed into your possession from an "email" to a "cold" - as in "I received a cold from Jacob yesterday."  I suggest that this latter use of "received" is sadly awry ... and for the reasons suggested!

Answer (score 2):

You can say this discussion may *get* too complicated.

But you cannot say this discussion may *receive* too complicated.

But when it means to gain possession of something, then *receive* is a bit more formal than *get*.

Comment: But "get" in your sentence is closer in meaning to "become", and means _a change in state_.That is why you cannot substitute "receive".

Comment: That’s a completely different context than the OP.